# Distinct mobile count is not work in crudRepository in spring application

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to make a query like:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT mobile) 
FROM qa_account.customer_contact 
WHERE customer_id=10001;
```

in crudRepository but getting a total count that includes duplicate too.
I don't want to write a native query.

Please give me some way to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to DISTINCT the whole SQL line, you could do something like

```
// Spring Data allows you to specify the entity you want to distinct after the word "Distinct"
List<CustomerContact> findDistinctMobileByCustomerId();

// Or before the word "Distinct"
List<CustomerContact> findMobileDistinctByCustomerId();
```

how to get count distinct

```
List<CustomerContact> listCustomerContact = yourRepository.findDistinctMobileByCustomerId(10001)
listCustomerContact.size();
```

I assume you have data like this

CUSTOMER_ID    MOBILE

10001              ________ A

10001 ________ A

10001 ________ B

10001 ________ C

The result output count distinct mobile = 3

More information on this, you can check into [Spring Data Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: i can do this, but dont want to get unwanted data thet is List of CustomerContact, i just need long value:

Comment: long referredCount = 
 customerContactRepository.countDistinctMobileByCustomerId(customerId);

Comment: I think your code should work try to debug sql first.

Comment: it gives me a non-distinct count of customer mobile so finally, I use nativeQuery for same.